# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: linux, oracle, yii, rhel, oci8

So I am trying to connect to oracle db using oci8 from php application. It works fine in windows. when i tried to move the php application into linux(RHEL6) it shows

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

I have oci8 installed in linux machine(RHEL6)

Oracle Server is running in windows

in my tnsnames.ora, listener.ora host names are 'localhost'.

like

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **localhost**)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Is it a problem? or else how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Oracle Listener service running? The most common cause of `No Listener` error is due to Oracle listener not running in the background.  You can configure it through `ntsysv` in Linux.

Comment: oracle server is running in windows . Application hosted in windows machine uses that service only. What i am doing is php application is in linux, oracle server is in windows

Answer (score 0):

Now its working fine

what i did ?

Created database services for LISTENER using Net Manager

Updated tnsnames.ora, listener.ora with my machine ip wherever 
i found localhost

like

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <ip>)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```